# String array not support in compile query

Tags: c#, linq

I have to pass string array in compile query of c# but not support .
 Can you give me another way ?

Error: The specified parameter 'searchStrings' of type 'System.String[]' is not valid. Only scalar parameters (such as Int32, Decimal, and Guid) are supported.

```
 static Func<ApplicationEntitiesEntities, int, int, string,string[], IEnumerable<DAL.Participant>> GetSearchParticipantModelCompile =
       CompiledQuery.Compile<ApplicationEntitiesEntities, int, int, string,string[], IEnumerable<DAL.Participant>>(
          (db, startIndex, recordCount, searchString,searchStrings) => (from s in db.Participants
                                                          where s.IsDeleted == false &&
                                                          searchStrings.Contains(s.MEMBERSHIP_Users.FirstName))
                                                          orderby s.MEMBERSHIP_Users.LastName
                                                          select s).Skip(startIndex).Take(recordCount));
```

Comment: please format this so it is readable...

Comment: oh my,  that is quite the unreadable monstrosity; can you just call out which bit is the string array? because `stringArray` only appears in the signature, not the query. So... which bit is failing? What is "not support"? Does it fail at runtime? And if so, what is the exact error message?

Comment: Yes   i just remove it  code , but when i used string array in query for match record  so runtime raised error

Comment: again: *what exact* runtime error? you aren't telling us what happened...

Comment: explain what is the error and will also be helpful to understand what you want to achieve (input and expected output) - there might be a more readable way to do this

Comment: I just edit code  and raised error  "The specified parameter 'searchStrings' of type 'System.String[]' is not valid. Only scalar parameters (such as Int32, Decimal, and Guid) are supported.
"

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, a compiled query wants to do as much prep work ahead of time as possible. This *simply isn't possible* when the input data is of varadic size, because the query can look very different for 0 items, 1 item, 2 items and 200 items. As a result, `CompiledQuery` may refuse to allow such queries. Options:

- have a few key sizes pre-generated via `CompiledQuery`, and use a `switch` on the `.Count` / `.Length` to choose one of these pre-compiled queries, with a `default` of using a query that isn't pre-compiled; for a real example from Stack Overflow:

  ```
  static readonly Func<DBContext, int, Post> _get1 =
      CompiledQuery.Compile((DBContext db, int id) => db.Posts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id));
  static readonly Func<DBContext, int, int, IEnumerable<Post>> _get2 =
      CompiledQuery.Compile((DBContext db, int id0, int id1) => db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == id0 || p.Id == id1));
  static readonly Func<DBContext, int, int, int, IEnumerable<Post>> _get3 =
      CompiledQuery.Compile((DBContext db, int id0, int id1, int id2) => db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == id0 || p.Id == id1 || p.Id == id2));
  static readonly Func<DBContext, int, int, int, int, IEnumerable<Post>> _get4 =
      CompiledQuery.Compile((DBContext db, int id0, int id1, int id2, int id3) => db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == id0 || p.Id == id1 || p.Id == id2 || p.Id == id3));
  static readonly Func<DBContext, int, int, int, int, int, IEnumerable<Post>> _get5 =
      CompiledQuery.Compile((DBContext db, int id0, int id1, int id2, int id3, int id4) => db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == id0 || p.Id == id1 || p.Id == id2 || p.Id == id3 || p.Id == id4));
  static readonly Func<DBContext, int, int, int, int, int, int, IEnumerable<Post>> _get6 =
      CompiledQuery.Compile((DBContext db, int id0, int id1, int id2, int id3, int id4, int id5) => db.Posts.Where(p => p.Id == id0 || p.Id == id1 || p.Id == id2 || p.Id == id3 || p.Id == id4 || p.Id == id5));
  ```

  with

  ```
     switch (remaining)
      {
          case 1: results.Add(_get1(Current.DB, ids[offset++])); break;
          case 2: results.AddRange(_get2(Current.DB, ids[offset++], ids[offset++])); break;
          case 3: results.AddRange(_get3(Current.DB, ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++])); break;
          case 4: results.AddRange(_get4(Current.DB, ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++])); break;
          case 5: results.AddRange(_get5(Current.DB, ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++])); break;
          default: results.AddRange(_get6(Current.DB, ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++], ids[offset++])); break;
      }
  ```

  (yes, really)
- write the SQL manually, perhaps using the [`STRING_SPLIT` feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx) in SQL Server 2016 to allow you to pass in a single parameter with delimited values. If that isn't available, you could use "table valued parameters", or you could just generate the TSQL and parameters appropriate to the specific runtime query.

Comment: I just create class and create property as a string array and pass to compile query   

 public class StringArray
    {
        public string[] str { get; set; }
    }

Same Error :  The specified use of parameter 'searchStrings' to produce a value of type 'System.String[]' is not supported by LINQ to Entities in a compiled query.